# TeamViewer remote computer application setting local computer Clipboard text

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, clipboard

I have a TeamViewer session open to a computer that runs an application that periodically sets the clipboard text programmatically. This application is somehow managing to set my clipboard text too. I suspect that TeamViewer is picking up the clipboard being set on the remote computer and setting my local computers to the same thinking that I had selected something.

Is there a way in team viewer to "disconnect" the input from myself, such as you can do in VMWare Workstation with (Ctrl + Alt)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable `Clipboard synchronization` by de-selecting it in the Advanced Category of Teamviewer Options.

To access options, click `Extras | Options` in the TeamViewer main window

Then select the `Advanced` category on the left and uncheck `Clipboard synchronization`

For more information see the [Teamviewer Manual](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/res/pdf/TeamViewer9-Manual-RemoteControl-en.pdf) where the relevant option is described on page 82.

Comment: There should be a quick way to toggle this in a session. The privacy implications of sharing the clipboard are just too huge, but the feature too essential.